# Grouping in minutes intervals starting at fixed time regardless the first row time and the date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series, pd.grouper

I have this code intended to count occurrences in 30-minute intervals; the requirement is to have these intervals at fixed starting points, minute 00 and minute 30 of each hour. Regretfully, despite every attempt of mine, the second group is aligned to minute 03 and minute 33.

I suspect that both the groups are aligned with the first time row and that the first one is correct just by chance. How can I tell the grouper to force the alignment to minutes 00 and 30?

```
# load and prepare data
df_long_forecast = pd.read_csv('df_long_forecast - reduced.csv')
df_long_forecast['after_12_max_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df_long_forecast['after_12_max_datetime']
)
df_long_forecast['after_12_max_time'] = (
    df_long_forecast['after_12_max_datetime']
    - df_long_forecast['after_12_max_datetime'].dt.normalize()
)  # timedelta64[ns]

# count the number of maxes happening after 12am (absolute and percentage)
hist_max = df_long_forecast.groupby(
    pd.Grouper(key='after_12_max_time', freq='30T', offset='0T', origin='epoch')
)['Date'].count()
display(hist_max)

# count the number of maxes after 12 that result in a profit trade
# (cannot be MORE than the previous ones)
df_long_forecast_profit = df_long_forecast[
    df_long_forecast['after_12_max_>_9_to_12_high'] > 0
]
profit_long = df_long_forecast_profit.groupby(
    pd.Grouper(key='after_12_max_time', freq='30T', offset='0T', origin='epoch')
)['Date'].count()
display(profit_long)
```

Here is `hist_max`

```
after_12_max_time
0 days 12:00:00    24
0 days 12:30:00     5
0 days 13:00:00     7
0 days 13:30:00     5
0 days 14:00:00     5
0 days 14:30:00     4
0 days 15:00:00     4
0 days 15:30:00     1
0 days 16:00:00     5
0 days 16:30:00     7
0 days 17:00:00     1
0 days 17:30:00     6
0 days 18:00:00     1
0 days 18:30:00     1
0 days 19:00:00     1
0 days 19:30:00     6
0 days 20:00:00     3
0 days 20:30:00     0
0 days 21:00:00     6
0 days 21:30:00    19
0 days 22:00:00     8
Freq: 30T, Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

and this is `profit_long`

```
after_12_max_time
0 days 12:03:00     8
0 days 12:33:00     4
0 days 13:03:00     5
0 days 13:33:00     4
0 days 14:03:00     5
0 days 14:33:00     4
0 days 15:03:00     3
0 days 15:33:00     2
0 days 16:03:00     5
0 days 16:33:00     6
0 days 17:03:00     2
0 days 17:33:00     5
0 days 18:03:00     1
0 days 18:33:00     2
0 days 19:03:00     0
0 days 19:33:00     5
0 days 20:03:00     3
0 days 20:33:00     0
0 days 21:03:00     6
0 days 21:33:00    21
0 days 22:03:00     3
Freq: 30T, Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

The CSV file with just the pertinent columns can be downloaded from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/mytcuez9yyb841vpj50vo/df_long_forecast-reduced.csv?rlkey=llnlvviird802ikxmkd3sjw15&dl=0).

Comment: It'd help to provide a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341), especially with less data. Three rows of output would be fine. You could also stand to use shorter, more memorable names and I think the calculations could be simplified for the sake of example too.

Comment: Have you tried using `resample` instead? I seem to remember `Grouper` has some quirks related to time groupings.

Comment: I cannot use resample since I have to group on different columns none of which is the index. I don't think it is so smart to reindex multiple times for each operation.

Comment: @wjandrea thank you, I don't know which is the row and the condition that potentially could trigger the trouble; so, if I provide just some rows hardly you can reproduce the trouble. The code is above at this link there is the full df_long_forecast  dataset in CSV format that can be imported after the first line of code above that can be ignored:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/qisatnwmraakiuegl1zt9/df_long_forecast.csv?rlkey=6wxbp4dqx4zgi6v8hle5r2ajn&dl=0

Comment: If the first line can be ignored, just get rid of it. Get rid of anything that's not relevant to the problem, including all those extra columns in the CSV. See [mre].

Comment: @wjandrea thank you for your valuable suggestions; I have edited the text accordingly with tested minimal usable code and reduced the number of columns to the minial one in the CSV file.

Comment: You can put `after_12_max_time` in the file and use `pd.to_timedelta` to parse it. That lets you get rid of the calculation and column `after_12_max_datetime` in this example. BTW, you could remove the redundant index column from the CSV.

Comment: "You can put after_12_max_time in the file" - no I believe this is an exaggeration, the problem could also be in the construction of that column. I am not a pro-python developer, otherwise I hadn't asked anything. I don't know how to remove the redundant index, it appears just in the CSV. Do you suggest using to_timedelta instead of groupby/grouper? Does this group by time ranges and not by date or will it create time ranges for distinguished days?

Comment: `to_timedelta` just converts to `TimeDelta`, that's all it does.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but you actually can use `resample` in this example. To specify a non-index column, you use the `on` parameter. Plus change `freq` to `rule`. But it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Pandas, because if you convert the timedeltas to timestamps (based on, say, the first day), you get the expected minutes.

The issue also affects resample, so I'm using it here for brevity.

Also, `offset='0T'` doesn't do anything as far as I'm aware, so I'm leaving it off.

```
# Base the time
first_day = df_long_forecast['after_12_max_datetime'].min().normalize()
df_long_forecast_profit['after_12_max_time_based'] = (
    df_long_forecast['after_12_max_time'] + first_day
)

profit_long_based = df_long_forecast_profit.resample(
    on='after_12_max_time_based',
    rule='30T',
    origin='epoch'
)['Date'].count()
profit_long_based
```

```
after_12_max_time_based
2020-01-02 12:00:00     8
2020-01-02 12:30:00     3
2020-01-02 13:00:00     6
                       ..
2020-01-02 21:00:00     6
2020-01-02 21:30:00    17
2020-01-02 22:00:00     7
Freq: 30T, Name: Date, Length: 21, dtype: int64
```

So as a workaround, you can do this then subtract the day again.

```
profit_long = profit_long_based.set_axis(
    (profit_long_based.index - first_day).rename('after_12_max_time')
)
profit_long
```

```
after_12_max_time
0 days 12:00:00     8
0 days 12:30:00     3
0 days 13:00:00     6
                   ..
0 days 21:00:00     6
0 days 21:30:00    17
0 days 22:00:00     7
Freq: 30T, Name: Date, Length: 21, dtype: int64
```

#### Additional bugs?

I played around with the resample and it looks like the `closed` and `label` parameters also have no effect on timedeltas, while they work fine for datetimes. For example, `label='right'`:

```
df_long_forecast_profit.resample(
    on='after_12_max_time',
    rule='30T',
    origin='epoch',
    label='right'
)['Date'].count()
```

```
after_12_max_time
0 days 12:03:00     8
0 days 12:33:00     4
0 days 13:03:00     5
                   ..
0 days 21:03:00     6
0 days 21:33:00    21
0 days 22:03:00     3
Freq: 30T, Name: Date, Length: 21, dtype: int64
```

vs

```
df_long_forecast_profit.resample(
    on='after_12_max_time_based',
    rule='30T',
    origin='epoch',
    label='right'
)['Date'].count()
```

```
after_12_max_time_based
2020-01-02 12:30:00     8
2020-01-02 13:00:00     3
2020-01-02 13:30:00     6
                       ..
2020-01-02 21:30:00     6
2020-01-02 22:00:00    17
2020-01-02 22:30:00     7
Freq: 30T, Name: Date, Length: 21, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you so much, I am astonished... it seems to me so strange that in the world nobody has encountered before this "bug". I will open and issue signalation in Pandas github, it may be useful.

Comment: after some tests I think there is still an issue: in case no data falls in a certain time interval, it is not generated an interval with 0 values, it is just skipped the group resulting in a misalignment in case of comparison with other complete grouping df.

Comment: For the record, the bug you opened: [QST: Grouping at fixed time intervals (hours and minutes) regardeless the date and the first row time #57642](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/57642)

Comment: @fede72bari I'm not sure what you mean; could you give an example? I'm confused because if you look at my `profit_long`, it has a 0 for 20:30. Plus, if you compare two Series, they automatically get aligned on the index, so I'm not sure how you'd have any misalignment.

Comment: Obviously it could be a mistake of mine too, but after further investigation, I think that this happens when the missing groups are at the beginning and not in the middle. I have another column in which from 12:00 to 14:00 there are no cases and when grouping in that way the groups start at 14:30. In the middle there is a 30-minute range group without cases and it is created with 0 countings. Do you think it is worth editing the question including this case? I don't know which is the policy in Stackoverflow in this case, I ask since you seem an expert on this.

Comment: @fede72bari I would say ask a new question like "How can I compare two Series but with missing values replaced with 0?", but I think you can just use `fill_value=0`, either in a comparison method like `.eq()` or aligning manually with `.align()` before the comparison.

Comment: Yes, maybe I can open another question. Actually, I have to create one unique df with 4 columns from 4 different groupings. Since at least one of them has the full groups using merge and then filling the remaining Nan with zeros fixed the trouble. But generally speaking, if all the 4 groups have had the first group missing values the results will have been different and not so easy to manage. I would say I opened a real issue on GitHub, not a general question, with all this sequence of attempts, workarounds and drawbacks including your answer here. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you’re facing is due to the `origin` parameter in the `pd.Grouper` function. The origin parameter sets the starting point for the grouping intervals.
When it’s set to `epoch`, it starts from the Unix epoch time (1970-01-01 00:00:00). If your data doesn’t align with this, you’ll get offsets in your intervals.

you can set the origin to a timestamp that aligns with these minutes.

```
origin = pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00') 

hist_max = df_long_forecast.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='after_12_max_time', freq='30T', offset='0T', origin=origin))['Date'].count()
percent_max = round(hist_max / hist_max.sum() * 100, 2)

df_long_forecast_profit = df_long_forecast[df_long_forecast['after_12_max_>_9_to_12_high'] > 0]
profit_long = df_long_forecast_profit.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='after_12_max_time', freq='30T', offset='0T', origin=origin))['Date'].count()
percent_profit_long = round(profit_long / hist_max.sum() * 100, 2)
```

This should give you the counts in 30-mins. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you for your attempt, but it doesn't work, I experience the same trouble. By the way, it is not clear to me why it should behave differently since in both cases (epoch and custom origin) the datetime is '1970-01-01 00:00:00'.